# pywinauto clicking button like element

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to automate one internal application and I have challenges in clicking specific "button like" control which can take me to the next page. When I print the control identifiers, it got printed as below

> HwndWrapper[.MainApplication.exe;;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] -
>   'MainWindow'    (L0, T0, R1299, B647) ['MainWindow',
>   'MainWindowHwndWrapper[.MainApplication.exe;;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]',
>   'HwndWrapper[.MainApplication.exe;;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]']
>   child_window(title="MainWindow",
>   class_name="HwndWrapper[.MainApplication.exe;;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]")

I have got the code as below:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application import time

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"<myapp>"') time.sleep(25)

hwnd = app.MainWindow
hwnd.Wait('ready')
hwnd.print_control_identifiers() 
hwnd.Click()
```

Using the appication, "Inspect", I can locate the element but I am not able to click on the same.

Could any one give me suggestion to proceed further?

Inspect output:

> How found:    Mouse move (156,295)    hwnd=0x000D009A 32bit
>   class="HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]" style=0x17080000
>   ex=0x40000 RuntimeId: "[7.7412.5972994]" BoundingRectangle:   {l:97
>   t:288 r:172 b:306} ProcessId: 7412 ControlType:   UIA_TextControlTypeId
>   (0xC364) LocalizedControlType:    "text" Name:    "Translator 1"
>   AcceleratorKey:   "" AccessKey:   "" HasKeyboardFocus:    false
>   IsKeyboardFocusable:  false IsEnabled:    true AutomationId:  ""
>   ClassName:    "TextBlock" HelpText:   "" ClickablePoint:  {x:134 y:297}
>   IsControlElement: true IsContentElement:  true IsPassword:    false
>   ItemType: "" IsOffscreen: false Orientation:  0 FrameworkId:  "WPF"
>   IsRequiredForForm:    false ItemStatus:   ""
>   ProviderDescription:  "[pid:7412,providerId:0x0 Main(parent
>   link):Unidentified Provider
>   (managed:MS.Internal.Automation.ElementProxy, PresentationCore,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxx)]"
>   IsDockPatternAvailable:   false IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable: false
>   IsGridItemPatternAvailable:   false IsGridPatternAvailable:   false
>   IsInvokePatternAvailable: false IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable:   false
>   IsRangeValuePatternAvailable: false IsScrollPatternAvailable: false
>   IsScrollItemPatternAvailable: false
>   IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:  false
>   IsSelectionPatternAvailable:  false IsTablePatternAvailable:  false
>   IsTableItemPatternAvailable:  false IsTextPatternAvailable:   false
>   IsTogglePatternAvailable: false IsTransformPatternAvailable:  false
>   IsValuePatternAvailable:  false IsWindowPatternAvailable: false
>   IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:  false
>   IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:    false FirstChild:   [null]
>   LastChild:    [null] Next:    [null] Previous:    [null] Other Props: Object
>   has no additional properties Children:    Container has no children
>   Ancestors:    "" button   "" pane     "" custom   "MainWindow" window
>     "Desktop 1" pane    [ No Parent ]

Comment: I am running this on Windows 10 64 bit machine, using Python 3 and pywinauto 0.6.3 When I tried with app.window(title="Translator 1", control_type="Text").click_input(), it throws the exception saying the element not found.

pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Translator 1', 'control_type': 'Text', 'backend': 'win32', 'process': 6340}

Comment: Is my answer helped to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Inspect.exe`, you must stick to UIA backend by `Application(backend='uia').start(...)`. Because your app looks like WPF one.

Read more details in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

If the button wasn't recognized as button, more universal way to do realistic click is method `.click_input()`.